# Converting cUrl token call to axios

Tags: javascript, curl, axios

I am trying to authenticate and API by calling to a seperate server, receiving a token to store, which is then used to Auth and API.

At the moment I have a token hardcoded in, because every time I submit a request with axios it returns `"error": "invalid_request"`

This cUrl script works fine `curl -v -X POST -u "username:password" -d "grant_type=client_credentials" https://thewebsite/token -H 'cache-control: no-cache'` and I can connect with Postman when I imported and added Basic Auth. I have tried to copy all the settings in, so many different ways.

I need to create an axios instance that is then passed to another function for the actual POST operation:

```
const settings = {
      baseURL,
      timeout: 5000,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      },
      auth: {
        username: username
        password: password
      },
      data: {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
      },
    };

this.axiosInstance = axios.create(settings);
```

In Postman the response looks like this:

```
"access_token": string,
"expires_in": 3600,
"token_type": "bearer"
```

I feel like it is an obvious syntax error, like the details need to be sent as a param or a header.